# VS Code IntelliSense not finding SFML (c++). Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, sfml

I am working on a personal project where I use SFML in my C++ code. When I created the project in VS Code a few weeks ago, I added the sfml using WSL. I noticed that IntelliSense wouldn't recognise SFML classes, and writing <SFML/...> would result in succesful compilation. This means the library is correctly included and linked during the build process. But I cannot seem to get IntelliSense to work with SFML.

For example, writing: `sf::` would not show a list of suggestions. When writing `sf::Sprite sprite` would leave sf colored blue and not green and Sprite white as opposed to blue, how it should be. Plus, when I hover above a definition of a class method in my project, I get a message saying "error-type".

[image: error-type]

I tried restarting VS Code, IntelliSense and I added a lib folder to my project where I added the SFML folder. The latter worked one evening. When I restarted my computer next day, it didn't work anymore. I also tried adding the path to the include folder in the c_cpp_proprties.json file.

I have looked around for any tutorials but none have worked so far. I do not need to compile my code through VS Code, I just need it to know SFML (mostly for autocompletion).

EDIT: I opened the project next day and the error changed. The "error-type" is gone but now all my SFML includes are underlined in red:
[image]

Here is my c_cpp_properties file:
[image]

Comment: Do you see red squiggles under the sfml includes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings (Shift-Control-P) and open "Remote Settings"

In that screen enter "include path" in the search box

Make sure it's under the Remote tab.

Then look for "C_Cpp Default: Include Path".

Click on "Add Item"

Add the path to your SFML includes in there.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thx for your comment. I do not have a remote tab, only user and workspace. Adding the path to c_cpp default doesn't change anything but adding it to the system include path does. The problem is that using that method it doesn't recognise the standard libaries anymore.

Comment: Did you add to the User **"Include Path"**?

Comment: yes I tried it both with User and Workspace

Comment: the only solution I found until now is creating a new project. I used your include path fix and it seems to recognise the library.

Comment: Something weird going on in the last project then. Glad it worked

Comment: I found the problem: whenever i open vscode the c/c++ extension would ask me if it was allowed to configure intellisense. By allowing that it changes some internal setting. If you have the same problem, just click "don't allow" and configure everything manually